# Storing Large Number of Time Series Data in Scala Dataframe with Common Key

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to store over 200,000 time series variables in a Spark data frame and I want to make sure the dates for each time series match up to a primary key set of all days between 1-1-1930 and 1-1-2017. The end goal being to build a bayesian based model that uses many time series as predictors for a specific time series. I read an XML time series into a Spark Dataframe that looks like this:

```
+---------------------+----------------------+
|timeSeries1_date     |timeSeries1_value     |
+---------------------+----------------------+
|           1997-01-01|                 10.49|
|           1997-01-02|                 15.64|
|           1997-01-03|                 53.06|
|                 ....|                  ....|
+---------------------+----------------------+
```

Right now I am attempting to do a full outer join to add each additional time series to the overall set of time series:

```
allSeries = allSeries.join(series, allSeries.col("date") === newSeries.col("timeSeries2_date"), "outer")
allSeries = allSeries.drop("timeSeries2_date")
```

The output looks like this:

```
+---------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|date                 |timeSeries1_value     |timeSeries2_value     |
+---------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|           1997-01-01|                 10.49|                 11.93|
|           1997-01-02|                 15.64|                  null|
|           1997-01-03|                 53.06|                 43.04|
|                 ....|                  ....|                  ....|
+---------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

This join becomes extremely slow to the point it is unusable. My experience is mostly with relational databases so I am having trouble grasping what the correct approach would be for this situation. Do I even need to join this data into the same Dataframe? Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using cross joins on large datasets - as you mentioned, it is prohibitively slow.

You could solve your problem by grouping data by timestamp (with a time granularity you need - `dayofmonth`, `hour`, `month` or `year`), and then apply an aggregation function with `agg` [API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/GroupedData.html) or a custom `UDAF`. For instance, if your task was to calculate a mean daily price for the following data frame:

```
scala> data.show()
+----------+-------+
| timestamp|  price|
+----------+-------+
|1997-01-01|  10.49|
|1997-01-01|1150.63|
|1997-01-02|  15.64|
|1997-01-03|  53.06|
+----------+-------+
```

You could achieve it as follows:

```
scala> data.groupBy(dayofmonth(col("timestamp")).alias("day")).agg(mean(col("price")).alias("mean_daily_price")).show()
+----+-----------------+
|day |mean_daily_price |
+----+-----------------+
|   1|580.5600000000001|
|   3|            53.06|
|   2|            15.64|
+----+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight! I am working with a fairly clean dataset that contains only one value per day, per month, or per year. My goal is to build a bayesian based time series model that models the affect of many indicator time series on one particular time series. I am not looking find the mean or calculate any values from within one time series. Are you saying that I can save each time series into a separate data frame and somehow aggregate that to into some sort of data frame?

Comment: I used `mean` as an example. You can use `UDAF` with some custom `evaluate` method. Can you give a (simplified) example of what kind of analysis you do with the output data frame? I.e. what do you do with matching `timeSeries1_value` and `timeSeries2_value`?

Comment: I use this tool https://google.github.io/CausalImpact/CausalImpact.html in R and it expects all the data to be in a matrix type format as I was attempting to achieve above. I don't need to follow that pattern exactly, but I do need to ensure that I am able to line up widely varying dates from each time series so I can correlate them.